# Designing letterhead templates for MS Word — continuation sheets

Tags: page-layout, template-design, microsoft-office, microsoft-word

I am in the process of designing a letterhead template for one of my clients so that he can use it as a template in MS Word.

I don't have MS Office installed myself, I use LibreOffice. We agreed that I would send over the template in the form of a `.docx` document with the header and footer elements using the parts that I've designed.

This all seems quite straightforward, but then I realised (in the middle of the job) that I need to allow the template to account for a continuation sheet, which is basically just a more basic version of the first page.

Is there a way I can set up the document like so?

- Front page template consisting of header + footer
- Continuation sheet with alternate header + footer
- Any subsequent pages use same continuation sheet layout automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's pretty much how you do it. You create a Section with the front page header/footer, and then the second page is a new Section with a different header/footer. The template which is given to the client is *always* two pages so that any typing spillover from Section 1 goes to Section 2, and then pages 3–N use the Section 2 header/footer.